# How can I set default localizer to lao language in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<LanguageService>();
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
        return factory.Create(nameof(SharedResource), assemblyName.Name);
    });

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("lo-LA"),
    };
   
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: "lo-LA", uiCulture: "lo-LA");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportCultures;
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider());
});
```

Set default to lao language is not working in ASP.NET Core MVC. The above code is from my `Program.cs` file.

Comment: Is it working as expected if you use other `CultureInfo()` apart from `CultureInfo("lo-LA")`?

Comment: still not working.

Comment: So itsm mean your resource file might not configured accordingly, have you tried to check applicaiton log? Does that throws any exception or error? Or even got executed?